# Summing all elements of a 1-dimensional array in Julia

Tags: arrays, sum, julia

It is quite a basic question, but I couldn't find a question related to this issue. Suppose there is an array of type `Array{Int64,1}`, and I want to sum all elements in the array. The syntax I found online is simply to use the function `sum` on the array, like the following:

```
sum([i for i in 1:999 if i%3==0 || i%5==0])
```

However I received an error message

```
MethodError: objects of type Int64 are not callable
```

The message also appears when I try the syntax in the stackoverflow posts asking for summing multi-dimensional array.
So what's the issue here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works for me:

```
julia> sum([i for i in 1:999 if i%3==0 || i%5==0])
233168
```

Try to restart Julia. It is possible that you have used `sum` as a variable previously, and now the compiler doesn't recognize it as a function.

Also, it's better to avoid the allocations. It's not necessary to create an array, just use a generator instead:

```
julia> sum(i for i in 1:999 if i%3==0 || i%5==0)
233168
```

The latter is more than twice as fast for me, and zero allocations.